# Can I make a method with code as input?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm a beginner at C++ and currently using an arduino (similar to C++, I was told to ask this question here).

I've written the following code:

```
int buttonPinState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonPinState != lastButtonPinState) {
    if (buttonPinState == 1) {  
      counter++; //Any random code goes here.
    }
  }
  lastButtonPinState = buttonPinState;
```

Is it possible to make a method out of this block of code where I would be able to change the "counter++;" to anything I need to execute?

Comment: While your question is on-topic here, a better site for these questions is http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Anyway, the specific task of reading a button is not so simple. All buttons have something called electromechanical signal bounce, that you need to filter out. Google "debouncing".

Comment: You really should have motivated more your question, and tell what is your arduino project about.

Answer (score 3):

you can use pointer to a function as an argument and then you can execute it within your if block.

```
void function(void (*arbitrary_function)()) {
    int buttonPinState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (buttonPinState != lastButtonPinState) {
        if (buttonPinState == 1) {  
            arbitrary_function();
        }
    }

    lastButtonPinState = buttonPinState;
}

void arbitrary_function_1() {
    // some code here
}


void arbitrary_function_2() {
    // some other code here
}

void loop() {
     ...
     function(&arbitrary_function_1);
     ...
     function(&arbitrary_function_2);
     ...
}
```

Comment: This response is not related to arduino coding (and way too complicated, I fear ;) )

Comment: When I think about it you might be right. Telling him to use pointer to a function as an argument might confuse him since he asks about making a piece of code a method. But I don't see how it is not related to arduino coding. Isn't it just plain C or C++ at the end? But maybe I am wrong :(

Comment: e.g. in Arduino coding the function main() is embedded in the framework. And there's no runtime function called printf.

Comment: I have addressed your comments but I still think that the answer answers exactly the question he asked since `function` executes code that is accepted as input.

Comment: Your answer code is lacking some client data, and should mention the [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) word.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I am not sure if your question is this simple that you want to execute a call if the `buttonPinState == 1` and it is `!=` to `lastButtonPinState`

Say if the condition you are looking forward to is true i.e. the button is pressed.

You do not need 2 seperate `if` conditions you can use `&&` and do what you intend is

**Solution 1:**

```
int buttonPinState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if ( (buttonPinState != lastButtonPinState) && (buttonPinState == 1) ) 
  {  
      counter++; //increment or do anything.

  }
  lastButtonPinState = buttonPinState;
```

**Solution 2:**

By calling a function

```
int buttonPinState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if ( (buttonPinState != lastButtonPinState) && (buttonPinState == 1) ) 
  {  
      functionCall(); //Call function to execute anything
  }

  lastButtonPinState = buttonPinState;

int functionCall()
{
   counter++;//increment counter
   // do your activity 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(I am separating the general question from its Arduino specific counterpart)</sup>

#### General considerations

Recommendation: **read [*SICP*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)**. It is not related to Arduino, but it is an excellent introduction to programming, freely available, and would teach you the right terminology and concepts.

<sup>[it seems that you are lacking a lot of general programming concepts; your question is probably not Arduino specific, and much less related to C or C++ that what you believe]</sup>

In general, it looks like you are *apparently* wanting [first class functional values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) or metaprogramming facilities. So read more about [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and about [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). For a tiny system like an Arduino, it might look like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and you should have motivated your question.

First class functions are generally implemented with [**closures**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). C don't have them, and C++ have them only since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (but I am not sure your Arduino cross-compiler is C++11 compliant). In C++11, you'll use [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Very probably, the programming languages available on Arduino don't provide first class functions and closures. You'll then use [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) (they exist in plain C99) thru [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29), that is with the additional *convention* of passing some client data. Then you can look at these (function pointer + callback client data) as a poor man's convention to implement closures.

Alternatively, you could consider generating some code at runtime and then calling it. This is a form of [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). You might want some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries (such as [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/)), but these requires that executable code can sit in RAM (as in every [Von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture)), which might not be the case for many Arduino boards (the code is only in Flash ROM, in some [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture)).

The abstract notion of [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) is also indirectly relevant.

---

#### Back to the Arduino:

Probably you could think of your code as some [finite state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) or [pushdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) stack automaton, or as some [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) interpreter. (so I guess you don't *really* need metaprogramming, or first class closures, even if your question relates to them). Maybe associate every button with some callback (that is use an array of pointers and callback client data)., e.g.

```
/// signature of callbacks
typedef void button_callback_sigt(int buttoncode, void*clientdata);

#define NB_BUTTONS 16
struct button_callback_st {
  button_callback_sigt* funptr; // function pointer
  void* data; // client data
};
struct button_callback_st buttoncb[NB_BUTTONS];
```

You'll then need some other code to initialize that array, and something to run the callbacks on button presses (and handle key [bounces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce)). Perhaps some callbacks might update that array (e.g. if some buttons are [modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28computer_interface%29), like the shift key on your keyboard).

You might want to have a "general purpose" [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) handling the buttons and removing glitches and key bounces (following the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle). Once it is sure that a button press is genuine (not a parasite), it will call the appropriate callback:

```
int buttonnumber = .... ;
(*buttoncb[buttonnumber].funptr) (buttonnumber, buttoncb[buttonnumber].data);
```

A concrete example of some callback could be indeed incrementing some global counter. Here is the number of the relevant button (in fact, you'll better have an `enum` describing the buttons)

```
#define COUNTBUTTON 3
```

Here is the counter, a global variable:

```
extern int counter;
```

The actual work of incrementing it is in this callback function. Its second argument is the address of the counter.

```
void counter_cbfun(int buttoncode, void*data) {
  int* pc = (int*)data;
  if (buttoncode == COUNTBUTTON)
     (*pc) ++;
};
```

and you'll initialize

```
  buttoncb[COUNTBUTTON].funptr = counter_cbfun; // function address
  buttoncb[COUNTBUTTON].data = (void*)&counter;
```

NB: Food for thought: http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: A perfect answer (but not for the TO). Kristian, you do not need to understand it, to advance from your status as "Beginner as C++" . I guess your question is rather "How to write a function and call it somewhere in loop(), e.g. when a digitalRead(button) changes its result". That has nothing to do with metaprogramming, closures, nor function pointers and callbacks.